# Testing for Google Analytics JavaScript calls on a page using CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to do functional testing of a website.

One thing we'd like to test is to make sure that Google Analytics is firing.

This blog post (http://viget.com/extend/testing-google-analytics-with-phantomjs) mentions using SinonJS (http://sinonjs.org) with PhantomJS - so I figured it should work with CasperJS.

I'm using `options.clientScripts()` to inject the script into the remote DOM:

```
casper.options.clientScripts.push("./sinon-1.7.3.js");
```

I'm then trying to call it within a CasperJS `evaluate()` call:

```
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        var spy = sinon.spy(_gaq, "push");
        console.log(spy.called);
        this.log(spy.called, 'debug');
    });
```

However, the `console.log` output doesn't seem to get pass through to CasperJS.

And the this.log is meant to be a CasperJS logging call, but I don't know if it'll work within `evaluate()` - and it doesn't seem to do anything here at all.

**Update:** I've also tried:

```
    spy = casper.evaluate(function() {
        var spy = sinon.spy(_gaq, "push");
        return spy;
    });
    this.log(spy, 'debug');
```

and I get:

```
FAIL TypeError: No default value
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: test_purchase.js:261
#    error: No default value
#           TypeError: No default value
#               at _replace (/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/modules/utils.js:261)
#    stack: not provided
```

**Update 2:** I've now got:

```
    spy = casper.evaluate(function() {
        var spy = sinon.spy(_gaq, "push");
        return spy;
    });
    this.echo('Has GA been called? ' + spy.called, 'debug');
```

which always returns false:

```
Has GA been called? false
```

I also tried using `waitFor()`, and that didn't seem to ever go true either:

```
    spy = casper.evaluate(function() {
        var spy = sinon.spy(_gaq, "push");
        return spy;
    });

    this.waitFor(function checkspy() {
        return this.evaluate(function() {
            return spy.called;
        });
    }, function then() {
        this.echo('Aha - GA has called: ' + spy.called, 'debug');
    });
```

which gives me:

```
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
FAIL "function checkspy() {
            return this.evaluate(function() {
                return spy.called;
            });
        }" did not evaluate to something truthy in 5000ms
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: test_purchase.js
#    error: "function checkspy() {
            return this.evaluate(function() {
                return spy.called;
            });
        }" did not evaluate to something truthy in 5000ms

#    stack: not provided
```

I'm guessing this may be some kind of timing issue, and GA hasn't been called yet? Is there some way of getting CasperJS to wait for the GA call, before running the evaluate()/SinonJS stuff? Or did I perhaps not inject it early enough?

Any idea of how to setup SinonJS and CasperJS correctly, so that we can detect if GA has been called?

Or does anybody know of any other way to correctly test Google Analytics firing within CasperJS (using SinonJS, or something else)?

Also - full disclosure - I did originally also ask this on the CasperJS Google Group (https://groups.google.com/d/topic/casperjs/shqwRoQ-CvE/discussion) last week - didn't get much of a response though.

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: Are you able to detect image requests? GA makes a request for a `gif` file with the tracking parameters every time it tracks anything

Comment: Hmm, is this the GA setup where you also host a copy of the tracking .gif on your local servers as well? I can look into that. However, ideally we'd like this to be something self-contained we can run locally using CasperJS, as a simple smoke-test during dev or before deployment.

Comment: No, GA always fires a gif in the standard setup. What your console for utm.gif being requested

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was - where the .gif is located on your own servers, rather than Google's servers? By default, I thought it only hit Google's servers for the .gif? What do you mean by console?

Comment: I see, the gif is located on Google's servers; by console I mean the Javascript console located in Web Developer tools of your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be able to proxy calls to _gaq.push like this:

```
var old_push = _gaq.push;
_gaq.push = function(options){
   console.log("Calling google analytics");
   old_push.call(this, options);
}
```